# Assets not showing up in production with "rails s" command with Chrome browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, google-chrome, asset-pipeline

None of my assets, such as images, javascripts, and styling features are showing up when I run the following command:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails s
```

Then I go to `http://localhost:3000` and the application comes up, but has no styling at all.

I did precompile the assets:

```
➜  myapp git:(master) ✗ bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace
 Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
 Execute assets:precompile
 /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/bin/ruby /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@myapp/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace
 Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
 Execute assets:precompile:all
 Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
 Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
 Execute assets:environment
 Invoke environment (first_time)
 Execute environment
 Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
 Execute tmp:cache:clear
 Execute assets:precompile:primary
 Invoke assets:precompile:nondigest (first_time)
 Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
 Execute assets:environment
 Invoke environment (first_time)
 Execute environment
 Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
 Execute tmp:cache:clear
 Execute assets:precompile:nondigest
```

This works just fine in `Safari`, can't figure out why `Chrome` won't load the stuff. I cleared out the browser cache also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `config/environments/production.rb`, make sure your application is configured to serve static assets:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

By default, Rails assumes that your static assets will be served elsewhere (e.g. Apache, Nginx, etc.)